# Efficient partitioning for installing ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

i am installing ubuntu first time alongside windows 8. So my comp is new. I have 5 partitions from manufacturer: EFI, 2 recovery partitions and C and D as NFTS. Windows is on C, D is empty.I am going to use windows very few. So i would like to allocate all the memory possible to ubuntu. I read everywhere that it is needed to shrink C to install ubuntu. So i will have freespace from C. But what about D? If it is empty and i would like also allocate it to Linux. How can i be sure to do it? What about other partitions? E.g. this EFI partition, do i need or maybe i can delete this partition to allocate to ubuntu as well? Would be great to have your advices! Thank you!

Comment: You do not need to shrink C if there are other options. If D is not going to be used, delete it, and use the free space for Ubuntu. The Ubuntu installer should have options to create partitions for Ubuntu out of that free space. Needless to say, you need a lot of practice to be sure, and gain confidence. I'd leave the EFI partition alone.

Comment: Best to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and if you have to shrink or change any NTFS partitions, do that from Windows and reboot to run chkdsk. Make backups of Windows and efi partition. Windows & Ubuntu will share the current efi partition.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just dual booted Windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04. I created recovery DVDs and then simply deleted the D drive, shrank C, and proceeded to use the empty space to create a regular partition (and a swap space) for Ubuntu. I did not mess with the EFI or the other partitions, so I can't tell you exactly what will happen with those, but since those come before the C drive, you might want to leave them alone. (I ran into problems when Windows was occupying partitions that were not right next to each other--not sure if Ubuntu will have the same issues.)